# Synchronising Two Signals

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, alignment, signals

I have two dataframes, but only one has fixed timesteps (=constant fps).
I want to align the blue curve on the orange curve by using some kind of cost minimization function or some other method.

How would i approach this problem?

I already tried dynamic-time-warping.

[image]